# Como unir 2 ou mais Objetos Json em Apenas 1

Tags: javascript, json

Como posso unir **dois** ou **mais** Objetos em **Json** de maneira que fique apenas **um** objeto **Json**, mas este, contendo **todos os dados unificados?**

De qual forma poderia ser feito essa união?

Exemplo abaixo:

```
Obj 1
[
0:{nome:"Fulano",idade:"30",...}
1:{nome:"Fulano2",idade:"45",...}
2:{nome:"Fulano3",idade:"78",...}
]

Obj 2
[
0:{nome:"Fulano6",idade:"45",...}
1:{nome:"Fulano7",idade:"20",...}
2:{nome:"Fulano9",idade:"45",...}
]

Ficando assim: 
[
0:{nome:"Fulano",idade:"30",...}
1:{nome:"Fulano2",idade:"45",...}
2:{nome:"Fulano3",idade:"78",...}
0:{nome:"Fulano6",idade:"45",...}
1:{nome:"Fulano7",idade:"20",...}
2:{nome:"Fulano9",idade:"45",...}
]
```

<sup>[Imagem do json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIE1n.jpg)</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O JS tem o método [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-PT/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) , que concatena dois arrays em um só.

Veja o exemplo

```js
var arrayA = [{
  nome: "fulano 1",
  idade: 30
}, {
  nome: "fulano 2",
  idade: 31
}, {
  nome: "fulano 3",
  idade: 32
}];

var arrayB = [{
  nome: "fulano 4",
  idade: 30
}, {
  nome: "fulano 5",
  idade: 31
}, {
  nome: "fulano 6",
  idade: 32
}];


var arrayC= arrayA.concat(arrayB);
console.log(arrayC);
```

Se houverem 3 (ou mais) arrays, você pode ligar com sucessivos concat

```
var arrayN= arrayA.concat(arrayB).concat(arrayC)...concat(arrayZ);
```

ou aninhar sucessivos

```
var arrayN= arrayA.concat(arrayB.concat(arrayC)...concat(arrayZ)))...));
```

Aqui um exemplo de 4 arrays com o método concat sucessivos:

```js
    var arrayA = [{
      nome: "fulano 1",
      idade: 30
    }, {
      nome: "fulano 2",
      idade: 31
    }, {
      nome: "fulano 3",
      idade: 32
    }];
    
    var arrayB = [{
      nome: "fulano 4",
      idade: 30
    }, {
      nome: "fulano 5",
      idade: 31
    }, {
      nome: "fulano 6",
      idade: 32
    }];

    var arrayC = [{
      nome: "fulano 7",
      idade: 30
    }, {
      nome: "fulano 8",
      idade: 31
    }, {
      nome: "fulano 9",
      idade: 32
    }];

    var arrayD = [{
      nome: "fulano 10",
      idade: 30
    }, {
      nome: "fulano 11",
      idade: 31
    }, {
      nome: "fulano 12",
      idade: 32
    }];

    var arrayN= arrayA.concat(arrayB).concat(arrayC).concat(arrayD);
    console.log(arrayN);
```

E aqui um exemplo de 4 arrays concact aninhados

```js
    var arrayA = [{
      nome: "fulano 1",
      idade: 30
    }, {
      nome: "fulano 2",
      idade: 31
    }, {
      nome: "fulano 3",
      idade: 32
    }];
    
    var arrayB = [{
      nome: "fulano 4",
      idade: 30
    }, {
      nome: "fulano 5",
      idade: 31
    }, {
      nome: "fulano 6",
      idade: 32
    }];

    var arrayC = [{
      nome: "fulano 7",
      idade: 30
    }, {
      nome: "fulano 8",
      idade: 31
    }, {
      nome: "fulano 9",
      idade: 32
    }];

    var arrayD = [{
      nome: "fulano 10",
      idade: 30
    }, {
      nome: "fulano 11",
      idade: 31
    }, {
      nome: "fulano 12",
      idade: 32
    }];

    var arrayN= arrayA.concat(arrayB.concat(arrayC.concat(arrayD)));
    console.log(arrayN);
```

Como você pode ver o resultado é o mesmo. Então qual é o melhor?

Particularmente eu opto sempre pelo que seja mais legível. Neste caso os sucessivos evitam se enganar na ordem de fechamento dos parenteses.

Answer (score 3):

Bom parecem duas arrays. Nesse caso, bastaria isto:

```
var arr1 = [{nome: "f1"}, {nome: "f2"}];
var arr2 = [{nome: "f3"}, {nome: "f4"}];
var junto = arr1.concat(arr2);
```

Comment: E se houver 3 ou mais arrays? Ficaria assim ?

var junto = arr1.concat(concat(arr2)arr3));

Comment: arr1.concat(arr2).concat(arr3)

Answer (score 0):

Boa noite amigos, vocês falaram sobre objetos em JavaScript no titulo; Porém depois no exemplo abaixo foi direcionado ao Objeto Array.

Eu consegui concatenar objetos dessa forma:

!Não Json's, Não Array's, Sim Objetos JavaScript.

Utilizando a API de Object.
Aonde passo os dois objetos e concatena em um novo com atributos referente a eles.

Exemplo:

```
obj1 = {
  par1,
  par2
};

obj2 = {
  par3,
  par4
};

Object.assign({obj1}, {obj2});
```

Retorno

```
{
    obj1: {
      par1,
      par2
    },
    obj2: {
      par3,
      par4
    }
}
```

Se eu quiser unir os atributos deles. Retiro os {} dos objetos parâmetros.

Segundo exemplo:

```
Object.assign(obj1, obj2);
```

Retorno

```
{
  par1,
  par2,
  par3,
  par4
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Você pode coloca-los em um Objeto Javascript, ficaria assim:

```js
//JSON
//Se estiver usando json_encode do php
//Vai receber algo parecido com isso.
var obj1 = {"nome":"Carlos","id":"140"};
var obj2 = {"nome":"Luciana","id":"20"};

//Criando Objeto JavaScript
//E atribuindo os json aos campos
var all = new Object();
all.a = obj1;
all.b = obj2;

//Acessando dados
console.log(all);
console.log(all.a);
console.log(all.a.nome);
```

Com os colchetes no JSON

```js
//JSON
var obj1 = [{"nome":"Carlos","id":"140"}];
var obj2 = [{"nome":"Luciana","id":"20"}];

//Criando Objeto JavaScript
//E atribuindo os json aos campos
var all = new Object();
all.a = obj1;
all.b = obj2;

//Acessando dados
console.log(all);
console.log(all.a[0]);
console.log(all.a[0].nome);
```